# MySQL get all records in each group, using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway to use `GROUP BY` in queries to grouping all records in each group?

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `betmatches` WHERE `status`='paid' GROUP BY `cpn`
```

but it results in getting only the first record in each group. I need all records per each group

Comment: what do you mean by *I need all records per each group*?

Comment: I mean, that query, returns only the first record in each group, if there was 5 records and cpn of 3 of them was `2` and cpn of other records was `4`, this query returns me only 2 records, i need all 5 records

Comment: The whole point of `GROUP BY` is to combine all the records in a group into a single row in the results.

Comment: I didn't know that, So there should be a solution for my purpose, no?

Comment: Maybe what you really want is `ORDER BY cpn`, so that all the rows with the same `cpn` will be next to each other in the results.

Comment: @Omid How could you learn about `GROUP BY` without knowing that? What did you think it was for? It's so you can use things like `MAX()`, `SUM()`, and `COUNT()` to combine all the records in a group.

Comment: @Barmar I was really busy lately and full of instability lately, So I'm confused about everything... this last project made me crazy ! sorry

Comment: If you show your input table and the result you're trying to get, maybe we can figure out what you really need to do. I suspect it's just `ORDER BY`.

Comment: thank you @Barmar It's been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the records, then you will have to add the column names in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Example:

Assume that betmatches have 5 columns `a,b,c,status` and `cpn`.You want the output with 3 columns a,b and cpn,Then add that 3 columns to `GROUP BY` and change `*` to the columns you want in the result set.

```
SELECT a,b,cpn FROM `betmatches` WHERE `status`='paid' GROUP BY `cpn`,a,b
```